# MySQL roles don't work in a Delphi application

Tags: mysql, delphi, roles, dbforge, mydac

I am using MariaDB10 with DBForge and creating a Delphi Project, I created a role to manage the permissions but it's not working good.

1 - Create a role on DbForge panel with a permission for a procedure `myprocedure`

2 - Add a Tmyquery in my Delphi project with the code `set default role myrole`

3 - Add a procedure on `afterConnect` calling the query created

4 - Set `disconnectedMode = true` on MyConnection options

Sometimes this process works, but most times I receive an Error: `Acess denied to user XX for routine myprocedure`

This happens with routines, functions and tables that I try to control the permissions

Besides that every time that I give a permission on a role and after edit the procedure the role loses the permission that I gave before

Obs: The roles work okey on DbForge panel is just when I tried to put this on Delphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user doesn't already have access to that role then them running `set default role myrole` doesn't give it to them.

> **SET DEFAULT ROLE requires these privileges:**
>
> Setting the default roles for another user requires the global CREATE
> USER privilege, or the UPDATE privilege for the mysql.default_roles
> system table.
>
> **Setting the default roles for yourself requires no special privileges,
> as long as the roles you want as the default have been granted to you.**

Comment: That quotes [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-default-role.html); for OP: [MariaDB 10.1.1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-default-role/)